# Random 10.10 Freeze Diagnosis

Tags: 10.10, freeze

I am running 10.10 Desktop version and it has been working for a month or so.  All of a sudden, I am getting "random" freezes from 5-15 minutes after startup.  The system never comes back and I have to reboot.  I am an Ubuntu/Linux newbie, so I don't know how to begin to diagnose the problem.   Another thing to mention is that I am running Linux inside of VirtualBox 4.0.4.

Are there logs I can checkout?  Anything else I can consider?  I can provide more level of detail if needed - I just don't know what else is relevant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by  VirtualBox and the fact that I had 4 virtual processors set for the virtual machine.  After changing this back to 1, everything worked correctly.